# How to use Hex Code or or predefined color in ColorStateList.valueof()

Tags: java, android, material-components-android

I'm trying to change my fab's color programmaticaly.So I found this code block It's actually works but I need to use a specific color on my colors.xml file or hex code

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(
floatingActionButton,
ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE) );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `#FF0000` with your desired color

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(floatingActionButton,
ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));
```

for resource xml color

```
ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(floatingActionButton,
ColorStateList.valueOf(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.your_color, null)));
```

Comment: thank you Mr. muhammad it worked you may edit your answer because second answer is deprecated but first one works thanks anyway